# How do you remove a sublist if a certain element is not found at a specific position across all sublists?

Tags: python, filter, sublist

In other words, if it's found that "f" is in the 4th position of the sublist, return that sublist, otherwise, exclude it if "f" is not found.

```
List = [['a','b','c','d','f'],['a','b','c','d','e'],['a','b','c','d','e'],['a','b','c','f','f'],['a','b']]
```

I have the following function which would work if all the sublists were the same size.

```
def Function(SM):
    return filter(lambda x: re.search("f",str(x[4])),List)

    IndexError: list index out of range

 Desired_List = [['a','b','c','d','f'],['a','b','c','f','f']]
```

I'm reluctant to use a for loop, because of the speed and efficiency costs. Are there any alternatives that are just as quick?

Comment: Lists are zero indexed, this means that `x[4]` will return the 5th item in the list. Do you mean to do `x[3]` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
lst = [['a','b','c'], ['a','b','c','d','f'],['a','b','c','d','e'],['a','b','c','d','e'],['a','b','c','f','f'],['a','b']]
lst_desired = [l for l in lst if len(l) >= 5 and l[4] == "f"]
print lst_desired
```

Output

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'f']]
```

Comment: alternative: `[l for l in lst if l[4:5] == ["f"]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> li=[['a','b','c','d','f'],['a','b','c','d','e'],['a','b','c','d','e'],['a','b','c','f','f'],['a','b']]
>>> filter(lambda l: l[4:5]==['f'], li)
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f', 'f']]
```